# Solving $y = x(y’ - x\cos x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve:

$$
y = x(y’-x \cos x)
$$

I tried to solve this as a linear equation:

$$
xy’-y=x \cos x \ /x \neq 0
$$

Getting:

$$
y’-(1/x)y= \cos x
$$

Therefore:

$$
y = \frac{\int( \cos x /x)dx+c}{1/x}
$$

Yet, the integral is quite problematic for me.

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `\cos` instead of simply `cos`, just see: $\cos x$ vs $cos x$.

Comment: Ok i fixed it thanks

Comment: Your mistake was that you didn't distribute the $x$ properly to the $x\cos x$. It should have eventually said $x^2\cos x$

Comment: @NinadMunshi i try again and again and still getting the same, particularly, not getting $x^2 \cos x$ That you said, where is my mistake?

Comment: It's literally the first line. What is $x\cdot x\cos x$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi OOOooooops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that under the substitution $y = xv \implies y' = v + xv'$:

$$xv = x(v+xv'-x\cos x) \implies v' = \cos x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got $y = x(\sin x + 1/ \pi)$, i think its right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = x(y’ - x\cos x)$$
$$xy'-y = x^2\cos x$$
$$\dfrac {xy'-y}{x^2} =\cos x$$
Rewrite it as:
$$\left (\dfrac yx \right )' =\cos x$$
Integrate both sides.